# How do I make this function apply to every word in a file?

Tags: python

I won't go into unnecessary details, but I have a function `convert` that transforms words into something else. Right now I want it to read a file and transform every word. Assume I already have the code that reads the file and transforms. The only problem is that convert seems to only work in very general terms for the argument I give it. For example, I write

```
return convert("string")
```

and every word in the file is transformed into the convert of "string." This is not what I'm trying to do.

What I want is for convert to be appropriately applied to every individual word. How can I make it so convert takes on a parameter other than a string I give it?

Answer (score 1):

```
word = ["dog", "cat", "cow", "mouse"]

for i in word:
    print convert("string")
```

will obviously print out four copies of the conversion of "string", not conversions of the four words.  You need to provide more detail on why you are passing a constant value "string", instead of the word you want to convert (in this case, `i`), as the parameter to your convert function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `convert` inverts a string (i.e., "hello" becomes "olleh").

```
def convert(input):
    return input[::-1]
```

Now, to apply `convert` to each string in an array, use Python's `map` function.

```
s = "this is a string of words"
a = s.split()
# a contains ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'words']
output = map(convert, a)
# output contains ['siht', 'si', 'a', 'gnirts', 'fo', 'sdrow']
```

Answer (score 0):

This program will randomly shuffle letters in all input words:

```
import random
import sys

def convert(item):
        ret=[x for x in item]
        random.shuffle(ret)
        return "".join(ret)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
                print " ".join(convert(word) for word in line.rstrip().split())
```

As you can see, `convert` is applied to each intput word. Is this the type of application you need?